# Position of reflexive pronoun in infinitive sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, infinitive, reflexive

Supposing we have the following sentence

> *Mit der Ersparnisse habe ich geschafft, ein Auto zu **[s. zulegen]** (With the economies I managed to take a car)*

I would like to ask about the position of reflexive pronoun of the verb in infinitive [zulegen] inside the sentence. Would it be something like:

> *Mit der Ersparnisse habe ich geschafft, ein Auto mich zu zulegen*

Comment: Nein, est is keine Frage. Meam culpa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct is:

> Mit **den** Ersparnisse**n** habe ich **es** geschafft, **mir** ein Auto **zuzulegen.**

**die Ersparnisse**

»Mit« needs an object that is in **Dativ** case (ask: »mit wem?«). And since you never have only one *Ersparnis*, you must use **Plural**. Dativ Plural of »die Ersparnis« is:

> den Ersparnissen

See also [*Ersparnis* in Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ersparnis)

**etwas schaffen**

The verb »etwas schaffen« (»to make/manage something«) is transitiv, so you always have to tell *what* you made. In this case, you describe what you managed to do in an subordinate clause, but a subordinate clause is not an object. So *schaffen* still needs an object that describes what you made, and in this case you use **es** (*it* in englisch):

> ich schaffe **es**
>   ich habe **es** geschafft

**zulegen**

The verb »zulegen« is reflexiv and transitiv, so it needs two objects. One is a Dativ-Objekt, that must be a personal pronoun, so it can be *mir*, *dir*, *sich*, *uns* or *euch*. Since we are talking about first person singular, it must be **mir**:

> Ich lege **mir** etwas zu.

The other object tells *what* you take (the car), and this must be in Akkusativ case, which you did right.

> Ich lege mir **ein Auto** zu.

The order of both objects is: 1. Dativ-Objekt (mir), 2. Akkusativ-Objekt (ein Auto). You use the same order in a subclause too.

Comment: one more question about this "es" we use with schaffen: is it an "es" like this we use when we refer to a whole sentence?

Comment: Das ist echt großzügig!